# I am trying to use getPicklistValuesRecordType adapter to get picklist values from Account Object.but Combobox is not visible on page

Tags: getpicklistvalues

```
.html
<template if:true={industryOptions}>
            <lightning-combobox name="industry" label="industry" value={selectedIndustry} placeholder="Select Industry"
                options={industryOptions} onchange={handleChange}>
            </lightning-combobox>
            <div> Selected Industry : {selectedIndustry}</div>
        </template>


<template if:true={ratingOptions}>
            <lightning-combobox name="Rating" label="Rating" value={selectedRating} placeholder="Select Rating"
                options={ratingOptions} onchange={handleChange}>
            </lightning-combobox>
            <div> Selected Rating : {selectedRating}</div>
        </template>
```

```
.js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValuesByRecordType, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
export default class GetPicklistValuesByRecordTypeAdapter extends LightningElement {

    ratingOptions;
    industryOptions;
    selectedRating;
    selectedIndustry;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT, recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId" })
    picklistHandler({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log(data);
            this.ratingOptions = this.picklistGenerator(data);
            this.industryOptions = this.picklistGenerator(data);
        }
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }


    picklistGenerator(data) {
        return data.values.map(item => ({ "label": item.label, "value": item.value }));
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        if (name === 'industry') {
            this.selectedIndustry = value;
        }
        if (name === 'rating') {
            this.selectedRating = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Check console if there is any error.

Comment: yes this error getting in console =>Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')]
    at GetPicklistValuesByRecordTypeAdapter.picklistGenerator (getPicklistValuesByRecordTypeAdapter.js:80:28)
    at GetPicklistValuesByRecordTypeAdapter.picklistHandler (getPicklistValuesByRecordTypeAdapter.js:70:37)

Comment: Yup, fix this and you are good to go.

Comment: If something is not working in LWC/Aura check console once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `picklistGenerator` method:

```js
picklistGenerator(data, fieldName) {
    return data.picklistFieldValues[fieldName].values.map((item) => ({
      label: item.label,
      value: item.value
    }));
}
```

Import the required fields:

```js
import RATING_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Rating";
import INDUSTRY_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry";
```

Call the method as below:

```js
this.ratingOptions = this.picklistGenerator(data, RATING_FIELD.fieldApiName);
this.industryOptions = this.picklistGenerator(data, INDUSTRY_FIELD.fieldApiName);
```

Comment: thanks. its worked